# Migrating from socket.io 0.9.x to 1.4.x - can't get socket.io to start

Tags: node.js, socket.io, migration

I am in the process of updating an old application to use socket.io 1.4 instead of 0.9 (and express 4 instead of 3) but I am unable to get socket.io to start up. In my old app I would set up things as follows:

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = socket.listen(server);
server.listen(8080);
```

According to the 1.x docs I thought this should work:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(8080);
```

I can't figure out what I am missing. Tried to add **io.listen(server)** as well in case passing the server wasn't enough, but that has no effect either. I don't think it is the syntax which is wrong... but I am obviously missing some step to get this working as before.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the second code block. Are you 100% sure there are no startup errors in the node console?  And, what symptoms are you seeing that tells you that you're unable to get socket.io to start up?  Are you sure you're doing the right thing on the client to connect to it?

Comment: You are right. It is working. But your comment brought me on the right track. It seems debugging messages are turned off by default in 1.x while they were on by default in 0.9.x So I kept looking for an 'info - socket.io started' which of course would never come ;) Thanks for the input!

Comment: Yes, you are not the first person fooled by that.

Comment: I posted an answer so you can accept that and indicate to the community that your question has been answered.

Comment: Socket.io v1.4 is not out yet. Are you running a specific branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to supply a useful answer here so you can close up the question.

Your second block of code is completely consistent with this combination shown in the socket.io doc.  The only difference is that they use the `.Server()` constructor and you use the `.createServer()` method which (if you look at the code) do the same thing:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(8080);
```

So, I don't think this is where the issue is.  Some things to check:

1. Are there any startup errors showing in the node console?
2. How do you know that socket.io is not started?  One difference in the post 1.0 world is that the socket.io server code does not output anything to the console when it starts like it did on the 0.9x world.  This has confused many.
3. If you still have issues, please show the corresponding client code.

---

Edit: As the OP discovered in comments when investigating some other things I asked, the socket.io server was starting just fine - the OP was just expecting to see some console output that used to be there before the 1.x version.